# Another method to move canvas objects?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I would like to know if besides canvas.move(), there is another method that allows to change the position of an object inside the canvas.
I would much rather setting a specific coordinations than moving the object.

Comment: in general in tkinter there is layout option of `.place(x=x_coord, y=y_coord)` that works for widgets so could try that one

Comment: It does not work on canvas objects from what I saw

Comment: okay, but I think You could put the canvas in a Frame and then put the frame in those coords

Comment: @Matiiss that will take too much time and work.

Comment: emmm, certainly not just create a simple frame and set canvas parent as that frame

Comment: `.coords()`, `.moveto()`

Comment: @YarinB do you want to move the whole canvas or objects on the canvas?

Comment: @Matiiss I assumed that OP wanted to move the object that is on the Canvas. I think you assumed that OP wants to move the actual Canvas.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned `canvas.move()`, I would assume they mean they want to change to position of objects *on* a canvas. To only other way to do that is via `.coords()` as @JacksonPro already pointed out.

Comment: @martineau I used `.bbox` instead of `.coords`. JacksonPro also mentioned `.moveto` but it isn't a `tkinter.Canvas` method

Comment: @TheLizzard I think that `canvas.moveto(tagOrId, x, y)` is a valid canvas method. It does seem to do what OP wants

Comment: @JacksonPro I saw a proposal to add the `moveto` function but it isn't in my tcl version (Python 3.7.9 TCL 8.6) that is why I said that `.moveto` doesn't work. I should have check other tcl versions - my bad

Comment: @TheLizzard: According to this [bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue23831) it looks like `moveto()` got added in Python 3.8.

Comment: @martineau thx I will update my answer

Comment: @TheLizzard: Also note that code can check the values of `tk.TkVersion` and `tk.TclVersion` (as well as Python interpreter version via `sys.version_info`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move an object on the Canvas, try this:
Try this:

```py
# In Python 3.8 and greater you can use this:
# `<tk.Canvas>.moveto(object, new_x, new_y)`
# like what @JacksonPro pointed out.
# but I am using python 3.7 so I am using this:

import tkinter as tk

def abs_move(self, _object, new_x, new_y):
    # Get the current object position
    x, y, *_ = self.bbox(_object)
    # Move the object
    self.move(_object, new_x-x, new_y-y)
# Monkey patch the `abs_move` method
tk.Canvas.abs_move = abs_move


"""
Testing script:
"""
# Moves the square to x=300
def move_square():
    canvas.abs_move(square, 300, 0)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=200, bg="cyan")
canvas.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Move square to x=300", command=move_square)
button.pack()

square = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill="black")

root.mainloop()
```

Another way is just to just call the tcl interpreter directly. Taken from [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue23831) - @martineau found it.

```py
# Works python 3.7 and greater

import tkinter as tk

def moveto(self, tagOrId, xPos, yPos):
    # Taken from https://bugs.python.org/issue23831
    """Move the items given by tagOrId in the canvas coordinate  
    space so that the first coordinate pair of the bottommost 
    item with tag tagOrId is located at position (xPos,yPos). 
    xPos and yPos may be the empty string, in which case the        
    corresponding coordinate will be unchanged. All items matching
    tagOrId remain in the same positions relative to each other.    
    This command returns an empty string. 
    """
    return self.tk.call(self._w, "moveto", tagOrId, xPos, yPos)
tk.Canvas.moveto = moveto


"""
Testing script:
"""
# Moves the square to x=300
def move_square():
    canvas.moveto(square, 300, 0)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=200, bg="cyan")
canvas.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Move square to x=300", command=move_square)
button.pack()

square = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill="black")

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to move the actual canvas, try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class MovableCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, bg=None, canvas_bg=None, canvas_width=None,
                 canvas_height=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, bg=bg, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg=canvas_bg, width=canvas_width,
                                height=canvas_height)
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

    def move_canvas(self, new_x, new_y):
        self.canvas.place(x=new_x, y=new_y)


# Moves the whole Canvas to x=300
def move_square():
    canvas.move_canvas(300, 0)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = MovableCanvas(root, width=400, height=200, canvas_width=100,
                       canvas_height=100, bg="cyan", canvas_bg="orange")
canvas.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Move square to x=300", command=move_square)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the option with the frame:

```
frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(x=60, y=60)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=100)
canvas.pack()
```